# I would like to rewrite an URL in php (.htaccess)

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting, get

This question might be a duplicate, but I didn't find any answer that helped me.
I would like to rewrite this url : https://example.com/mobilier.php?is=24&s=tables into https://example.com/mobilier/24/tables
And this url : https://example.com/product.php?id=110&nom=table-de-nuit into https://example.com/product/110/table-de-nuit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .htaccess rules

```
redirectMatch 301 ^example.com/mobilier.php?is=24&s=tables$ https://example.com/mobilier/24/tables
redirectMatch 301 ^example.com/product.php?id=110&nom=table-de-nuit$ https://example.com/product/110/table-de-nuit
```

if you want to do this for a lot of urls, reconsider your way of doing things